# How to write this LINQ query to get a particular claim from Identity oauth

Tags: linq, claims-based-identity

I have a list of claims in my object and I want to look for a particular claim with its name and find its value which is Boolean. I wrote the following query but I am getting the error saying that I can't use '&&' operator on string and Boolean operands.

```
bool isSSO = context.Ticket.Identity.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "IsSSO"&& c.Value);
```

Please advise.

Comment: And what do you want c.Value to compare to?

Comment: To be sure `c.Type` is `string` and `c.Value` is `bool`?

Comment: @Arturo: yeah, c.Type is string and c.Value is bool and I want to set the isSSO variable based on the value of c.Value

Comment: @Dinotom: I don't want to compare it to any value. What I want is something like "Select c.value from claims where c.Type == "IsSSO" "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Claim.Value` property is `string`, probably you are receiving values like `"true"` or `"false"`. Try this:

```
bool isSSO = context.Ticket.Identity.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "IsSSO" && bool.Parse(c.Value));
```